# Why is serprent considered untrusted?

Tags: security, oracles, external-api

[Serpent was way to fetch Diesel prices from the oraclize api at fixed intervals](https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/blob/master/serpent-deprecated/DieselPricePeg.se).

On GitHub, it s written audits proved the code to be flawed, but where are such audits? I m meaning why is it flawed?

Comment: https://blog.openzeppelin.com/serpent-compiler-audit-3095d1257929/

Comment: @Ismael I m talking about https://github.com/provable-things/ethereum-examples/tree/master/serpent-deprecated not the language.

Comment: The compiler has critical bugs. There wasn't enough interest in fixing it since solidity was supported and well maintained. Other projects started deprecating serpent because nobody was fixing the compiler bugs.